# How do I verify text on one page then validate it is that same text on another page using Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

For Example: Log into a webpage that has text (unknown to user), then verify it has the same text on another page.

Comment: Are you asking to compare a full pages text or just one element?  Quick answer is to get the text from the 1st page and save it to a variable.  Go to the second page, get the text and compare.  Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm looking to print text on one page then validate the same text on another page. thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify, you want to input text on one page and then verify this text shows up on a second page?

Answer (score 0):

You could go for something like:

1. Locate [HTML Body](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp) object for the first page using [XPath](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727) like:

   ```
   driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body"))
   ```
2. Get [innerText property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) value of the HTML body
3. Split it into separate strings using [line separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character
4. Perform steps 1 - 3 for the second page
5. Iterate the strings extracted from the first page and look for matches in the strings from the second page
6. Do what you need with the results

Example code:

```
driver.Url = "https://stackoverflow.com";

string firstPageText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).GetAttribute("innerText");
HashSet<string> firstPageLines = new HashSet<string>(firstPageText.Split('\n'));

driver.Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56366177/how-do-i-verify-text-on-one-page-then-validate-it-is-that-same-text-on-another-p";

string secondPageText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).GetAttribute("innerText");
HashSet<string> secondPageLines = new HashSet<string>(secondPageText.Split('\n'));

foreach (string line in firstPageLines) {
    if (secondPageLines.Contains(line)) {
        Console.WriteLine("This line is present in both pages: " + line);
    }
}
```

Example output:

[image]